# How to run Nginx with Node.js on Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I want to install Nginx on Windows, and to run two node application. How can I do this?

I've tried to download Nginx 1.6.3, but I don't find something relevant about how to run on Windows. Just for Linux. I think there should be some modules for node.

Any advice will be useful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I never run Nginx on Windows, but the official documentation says how: http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html.

To run two node applications with Nginx, it's necessary to create a proxy. This is an example of how to alter the **nginx.conf** file for this:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
        include mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        sendfile on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        gzip on;
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        access_log C:\var\log\nginx\access.log;
                location ~ ^/(javascripts|stylesheets|images) {
                root C:\app1\public;
                expires max;
        }
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
  }
server {
        listen 81;
        server_name localhost;
        access_log C:\var\log\nginx\access.log;
                location ~ ^/(javascripts|stylesheets|images) {
                root C:\app2\public;
                expires max;
        }
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        }
  }
}
```

In this case, there are two node applications, one running on port 3000 and an other on port 3001 - the Nginx works as a proxy.

Further documentation: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/.

In your case, the configuration file are localised in: `C:\nginx_v1_6\conf\nginx.conf`

Backup the default file and update the content with what I posted.

Finally, you can test the reverse-proxy through `localhost` (port 80 default) and `localhost:81`, if the nodes servers and Nginx server are running.

Comment: I've downloaded version 1.6.3 for windows.You give me the configuration file.How should i modify this to run two node applications? ..let's say app1 and app2..

Comment: Do you follow the instructions of the installations for Windows? I do this here and it works. In the directory unziped after downloaded nginx, has a directory named "conf", and inside it, a file nginx.conf. This file you alter how I posted here, adapting the paths ("/var/log/nginx/access.log", "/var/www/app2/public") for the path of the project in Windows. This example the node project use Express Framework. For the proxy works, the two node applications alread running in the ports (in my example, onde running in port 3000 and another 3001); the ports must be different.

Comment: i've downloaded and unzipped nginx...But i don't understand where to put my apps...every app have a server.js file that must be running...i must create the var directory or?

Comment: And what is    javascripts|stylesheets|images? ..a directory from where?..i'm confused...

Comment: Each app only need running (localhost:3000 and localhost 3001 for example). Then configure reverse-proxy in nginx https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/. "I must create the var directory or?" It's good to storage the log and the path you can define. "And what is javascripts|stylesheets|images? ..a directory from where?" - In case of express, to access javascripts, stylessheets and images has create a rule for access localhost:3000/javascripts/common.js for example. This is absolute path for their.

Comment: ok..i will say in another mode: i have an app in /app1/server.js running on port 3000.Another app in /app2/server2.js running on port 3001.How should look the nginx conf file ?

Comment: What is the command to run nginx from node's folder?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some instructions on how to install nginx for Windows:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Comment: how will your comment help with the question?