# Nginx nodejs on same port in windows

Tags: node.js, nginx, windows-10

This question was already answered in [How to run Nginx with Node.js on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460440/how-to-run-nginx-with-node-js-on-windows). However following that doesn't seem to work. Then I went to http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html which doesn't help much. Here is a brief about my problem.

jxcore is running on http://localhost:3434/ and successful serves a test file hello.js

Nginx on port 80 works fine as usual.

So to get it redirected I have followed the above url and below is my current configuration.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log D:\nginx-1.10.1\logs\access.log;
            location ~ ^/(javascripts|stylesheets|images) {
            expires max;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm; #i tried adding hello.js here as well but didn't work
    }

    location /pubsub { #node js files are in a sub directory under nginx root
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3434;
    }
}
```

after i restart nginx and go to localhost it serves the static files. but when i go to localhost/pubsub it just gives 403 Forbidden. It says a permission issue but when configuring nginx in windows, nowhere it says that you need to meddle with permissions as in *nix installations?

Comment: What happens if you proxy from `/` instead of `/pubsub`? does it makes to the node app?

Comment: nope it doesn't work that way either because my normal site location is / and you can't add another / in the location field. If i do nginx complains about incorrect configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! this was sorted out by accident! :)

initially my redirection was done as below. idea was if someone goes to localhost/pubsub it should redirect to nodejs, which didn't work. it was showing a 403

```
location /pubsub { #node js files are in a sub directory under nginx root
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3434;
}
```

Working configuration was;

```
location /pubsub/ { # notice the trailing slash
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3434;
}
```

I also added my default .js file to Index parameter.

That's all and now http://localhost/pubsub goes to node!